# How can I let a growing div overflow visibly without its parent getting a scrollbar (while having different overflow behaviour for x & y)?

Tags: html, css

I'm stuck with the overflow behaviour...
The up-scaled div should be visible without the parent getting a scroll-bar.

```css
section {
  background: grey;
  overflow-x: scroll; /* should stay like this and works :D */
  overflow-y: visible; /* does not work correctly */

  width: 100vw;
  display: flex;
  gap: 1rem;
}

div {
  background: red;
  transition: transform 0.1s ease-in-out;

  height: 100px;
  min-width: 300px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

div:hover {
  transform: scale(1.5);
}
```

```html
<section>
  <div>1</div>
  <div>2</div>
  <div>3</div>
</section>
```

Comment: Where do you want the horizontal scrollbar to be when a div scales?

Comment: This is how it works according to the [spec](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/overflow). Setting one axis to `visible` (the default) while setting the other to a *different* value results in `visible` behaving as `auto`. What are you trying to make? Maybe you need another approach.